# how to write new string in the end of the line in csv file by C

Tags: c, csv

I am writing a C code which need to add the new information in the end of the line if the condition match.

```
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r+");

    //read every line if line!=NULL
    while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){
        //split the line by sep
        split(line, ',', fields);       
        fprintf(file,",%d,%d,%d",D,F,G);
   }
```

It is the code I try to write the matched information. However, it will write the information in the beginning of the line. Is that possible I can move the "file" pointer to the end of the line?

Comment: Even if you do, that will overwrite the beginning of the next line.  I suggest writing to a different file.

Comment: Hi @interjay , you are right. However, the file that I would like to add information into will be large so open a different file and write them will take a longer time if I only want to add a little information. For example, the file is 10G but I only add 100KB in it.

Comment: You simply can't add data in the middle of a file like that, you really have no choice than to write to a temporary file, then rename it over the original file when done. Also, having a 10G large CSV file? That alone is an enormous [WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)! A 10G text file is a certain sign of something gone horribly wrong somewhere in the development process.

Comment: You possibly should consider to switch away entirely from csv file to some database. This is exactly the use case where with a (relational) database you would simply add another table...

Comment: 10G csv file parsing :O ? IMHO a script would be better choice than a c - program for this.

Comment: And you think _inserting_ into an existing file is faster? Likely not (it actually depends on the FS). The other comments are right - use a database.

Comment: @kkk: Why would it? There might be better languages for this, but they are also likely slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to follow couple more steps

Open a temporary file along with existing file

```
FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
FILE *tmpFile = fopen(tempFileName, "a+" );
```

get a line from existing file, trim Next line append your fields after comma, probably create comma separated string of extra fields

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){
```

Remove New line and add your paremeters

```
    if( line[ strlen(line) - 1  ] == '\n' )
        line[ strlen(line) - 1  ] = '\0';

    fprintf(tmpFile,"%s,%s\n",line, your_field); // Write to temporary file
}
```

Delete old file unlink is probably useful

```
man -a unlink
```

and then rename temp file to original file

```
man -a rename
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing what you want. You can't insert bytes in the middle of a file.

However, if you have spaces or something similar that allows bytes to be written into the file without overwriting data, you could accomplish something close to what you want. Say you have the lines

```
"1,2,3,            "
"4,5,6,            "
```

(note the space) you could insert text there. I would use two file pointers:

- get the position from read file pointer when the line starts
- read the line using that file pointer
- add the number of bytes until the first space to the position
- seek on the other file pointer to this position
- write the new data and make sure there's enough space

The first file pointer would be in "read" mode, the second in "write" mode and none in "truncate" because that would screw up your file.

Or use a much better database format. ;)